# Need a method to send message using GPS on android application without network

Tags: android, web-services, web, gps, sms

Looking for a way to send the message between two phone from android using GPS, As soon as the person reaches certain Position the GPS mapped to another phone should either show like flash success if person is moving it should show as proceeding and click on emergency it should send danger alert and latitude, longitude details. Is there a way to do this. Ok to use any technology for this to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only GPS technology that might allow this is the new European system called Galileo. Still it was rolled out few weeks ago for positioning and not yet for third party messaging, also it is not known if will be an open technology for everyone to use or if it will be a service for major companies.

Beside all of this not many phones as of today can receive the Galileo signals because of different frequencies and protocols so there is no way of doing what you are asking for

Comment: Is there a any suggestion I can go with, to communicate on a non-network zone, like on mountains or High altitude terrains?

Comment: Maybe you can use some kind of radio frequencies but I am not sure what is the signal coverage in such places

Answer (score 1):

> Looking for a way to send the message between two phone from android using GPS

That is not possible. GPS is not an ad-hoc communications medium that you or other people can use.

Comment: Oh ok, So there is no way we can communicate using GPS technology?

Comment: @ChandraKanth: Correct.

Comment: Is there anything I can use except GPS communication that work for communication purpose, except satellite phones?

Comment: @ChandraKanth: For short distances, use WifiDirect, Bluetooth, or NFC. For long distances, no.

Comment: It is quite long distance so I guess nothing as of now we can look for @CommnsWare Thank u much